# Error output if a wrong number or char is inserted while in a loop

Tags: c

I'm trying to make a program that generates random numbers and has the user guessing the answer of the sum of those numbers! I don't know how to send a wrong input message if the user inserts say the letter d. And if he inserts the letter s or S the program just finishes the for loop.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include<time.h>

main(void){
  int num1,num,result,resultuser;
  int i;
  //char s,S;
  srand(time(NULL));    
  printf("Numeros:");

  for(i=0 ; i<10 ; i++) {
    num1 =  ( rand()%50 );
    num = ( rand()%50 );

    printf("Qual o resultado da conta: %i + %i =", num,num1);
    scanf("%i",&resultuser);

    result = num + num1;

    if (result == resultuser){
      printf("Correto!\n\n");
    } else{
      printf("Errado!\n\n");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: So your real question is how to "edit" the user's input...?

Answer (score 1):

The return code for `scanf` is the number of elements successfully parsed. In your situation, you would expect it to be 1 if the integer is successfully parsed.

If you save the return code from scanf, you can identify when the number of parsed elements was 0, ie, that it couldn't parse an integer as you requested. At this point, you can print to the user that they did not enter a valid number.

Comment: Enduser must also handle the condition where a partially valid input is made, such as "12abc", which scanf would report that it successfully parsed "1" integer, but "12abc" is not exclusively an integer.

Comment: Indeed. Another option that could be considered is to read the entire line and pass it to `atoi`, except that atoi may cause undefined behavior in this case... so perhaps we could look at `strtol`, which has better safety promises? But no, `strtol` returns 0 when it cannot successfully convert, which is hard to tell from a real 0. The standard library here doesn't make life easy: it may be worth reading the whole string, doing a quick pass for invalid chars, and then sending to `strtol` when we're happy with it.

Comment: To detect no conversion in `strtol(some_string, &endptr, 10)`, rather than look for a return value of 0, test if `endptr == some_string`.  The "quick pass" method will still pass `"--123"` which will fail `strtol()`.

Answer (score 0):

Read input using `fget()` and then parse it for the `int` or letter.

```
    printf("Qual o resultado da conta: %i + %i =", num,num1);

    char buffer[100];
    if (fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, stdin) == NULL) {
      // EOF or error detect, quit the loop
      break;
    }

    // Test if a number was found
    if (sscanf(buffer, "%i", &resultuser) != 1) {
      // use `resultuser`
    } else if (buffer[0] == 's' || buffer[0] == 'S') {
      // exit the loop normally as S was found
      break;
    } else {
      // bad input detected
    }
```